# How to move UILabels with the UIView when the UIView is resized?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am trying to move my `UIView` and `UILabel`s in tandem with each other upon resizing the `UIView` but the `UILabel`s remain fixed in their position when I change the width of the view. In my `UIView` I have a `UIBezierPath` that's filled with a gradient. It might be my auto layout constraints that's preventing the labels from adjusting with the view but i'm not entirely sure.

```
//changeUIViewSize set in view controller
var changeUIViewSize: Double? 
let mess = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 450, height: 31)
let insetRect = CGRectInset(mess, lineWidth / 2 , lineWidth / 2)
let bounds = CGRect(x: 0.5, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)

let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: insetRect, cornerRadius: 10)
path.addClip()

//Gradient Code....


//Scale frame width
self.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.bounds.width * changeUIViewSize, self.bounds.height)
```

In this picture, I would prefer the 90 to be right next the colorbar but instead it's at the position to the right of the original `UIView` size.

[image]

Comment: You have constraints that are preventing it from being right next to the color bar.

Comment: @iosDev82 I can't figure out what the constraints that are doing that might be. I have horizontal constraints from the UILabel to the UIView and the from the UILabel a trailing space to the margin